# DatacontractSerializer for desktop applications

Tags: c#, datacontractserializer

While searching for the DataContractSerialization I have found various articles which mentions that DataContractSerialization is used with WCF. Now I am working on one of desktop application with .net 4.0(not any kind of service). This application have variuos data to serialize.

By looking at the features of DataContractSerialization I want to use DataContractSerialization for my application.

So please tell me whether DataContractSerialization can be used for desktop applications and any guidlines for handling the versioning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use datacontractserializer for desktop applications no problems. As for versioning, you can add new members to an existing data contract, and quite easily handle missing data.

However, if you want to remove fields or change the meaning of existing fields (e.g. your shoe property "size" used to be a eur size but is now a UK shoesize) then it quickly gets difficult. Then you should create a new contract version. See this question: [Simple data file versioning with DataContractSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513589/simple-data-file-versioning-with-datacontractserializer).

Here is a document from microsoft on [versioning strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff384251.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, DataContractSerializer was written *for use by* WCF, but it is separate and self-contained, and can be used without using WCF in any way. It is even in a separate assembly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use it. Xml Serialization have some kind of disadvantages when you try to serialize dictionaries and lists. But DataContractSerialization  Provides all the feature we need.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Any guidlines for the versioning using DataContractSerialization.

Comment: It is available from .Net frmwrk 3.5 sp1.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can.

Aside from that WCF does ***not*** exclude Desktop apps - it can be hosted in a desktop application by using the [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx) class.