# Error during the Xml deserialization with data contract in c#

Tags: c#, xml, deserialization, datacontract, xml-deserialization

I know the argument was faced so many times, but I am a newbie and I don't understand how to manage the error.
I've a Stream XML and I would like to deserialize it with data contract method.
Do you notice where I'm making something wrong?

Here is the xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<response>
    <sessid>jsh5ekqnt39117tmu5gjebkku4</sessid>
    <session_name>Name Session</session_name>
    <user>
        <uid>2</uid>
        <vID>1</vID>
        <roleId>1</roleId>
        <username>mail@example.com</username>
        <password>password</password>
        <dateCreation>2013-05-14 00:00:00</dateCreation>
        <dateLastLogin>2013-09-06 09:22:10</dateLastLogin>
        <enabled>1</enabled>
        <multisession>1</multisession>
        <iddID>4</iddID>
        <iddName>Nome</iddName>
        <iddSurname>Cognome</iddSurname>
        <iddMobile>32222222</iddMobile>
        <iddEmail>mail@mail.mi</iddEmail>
        <iddTelephone></iddTelephone>
        <iddFax></iddFax>
        <iddNotice></iddNotice>
        <roles>manager</roles>
    </user>
    <result>1</result>
</response>
```

Here is the data contract:

```
namespace XmlAnalyzer.Ws {
    [Serializable()]
    public class LoginResponseContract {
        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("uid")]
        public string Uid { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("username")]
        public string Username { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("iddName")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement("iddSurname")]
        public string Surname { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the code:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)_webRequest.GetResponse();
Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(LoginResponseContract));
LoginResponseContract loginResponseContract = (LoginResponseContract)xs.Deserialize(streamXmlAuthentication);
```

This is the exception:

> The request was aborted: The connection was closed unexpectedly.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this serialization specifically but shouldn't the class have the same hierarchy as the xml object and exactly the same naming? (e.g.: surname <=> iddSurnam)

Comment: right, I corrected, but the problem is still the same.

Comment: could you update your question with the updated class?

Comment: this is corrected, with the right tags, but there's still the same problem of connection closed.

Comment: I think it should be completely right and not only the naming but the hierarchy as well. A working example of deserialization can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943176/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-datacontractserializer Make sure to add the order attributes as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my try to deserialisate the data. I hope this helps you.

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\r\n<response>\r\n<sessid>jsh5ekqnt39117tmu5gjebkku4</sessid>\r\n<session_name>Name Session</session_name>\r\n<user>\r\n<uid>2</uid>\r\n<vID>1</vID>\r\n<roleId>1</roleId>\r\n<username>mail@example.com</username>\r\n<password>password</password>\r\n<dateCreation>2013-05-14 00:00:00</dateCreation>\r\n<dateLastLogin>2013-09-06 09:22:10</dateLastLogin>\r\n<enabled>1</enabled>\r\n<multisession>1</multisession>\r\n<iddID>4</iddID>\r\n<iddName>Nome</iddName>\r\n<iddSurname>Cognome</iddSurname>\r\n<iddMobile>32222222</iddMobile>\r\n<iddEmail>mail@mail.mi</iddEmail>\r\n<iddTelephone></iddTelephone>\r\n<iddFax></iddFax>\r\n<iddNotice></iddNotice>\r\n<roles>manager</roles>\r\n</user>\r\n<result>1</result>\r\n</response>";
        Stream s = new MemoryStream(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(xml));
        XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Response));
        Response loginResponseContract = (Response)xs.Deserialize(s);
        Console.WriteLine(loginResponseContract.User.iddName);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

[Serializable, XmlRoot("response")]
public class Response {
    [XmlElement("sessid")]
    public string SessionID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("session_name")]
    public string SessionName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("user")]
    public UserDetail User { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("response")]
    public int result { get; set; }
}

[Serializable]
public class UserDetail {
    [XmlElement("uid")]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("vID")]
    public int vID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("roleId")]
    public int RoleID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("username")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dateCreation")]
    public string Creation { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("dateLastLogin")]
    public string LastLogin { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("enabled")]
    public int Enabled { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("multisession")]
    public int Multisession { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddID")]
    public string iddID { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddName")]
    public string iddName { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddSurname")]
    public string iddSurname { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddMobile")]
    public string iddMobile { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddEmail")]
    public string iddEmail { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddTelephone")]
    public string iddTelephone { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddFax")]
    public string iddFax { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("iddNotice")]
    public string iddNotice { get; set; }
    [XmlElement("roles")]
    public string Roles { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: How should I behave if my response has more tag **<User>** and I should have an array of User in my UserDetail data contract? Because I find myself in this situation, and I got only one user, and not them all. I guess I should create Users and then UserDetail, right?

Comment: You mean you have multiple user tags in your response tag? That would be quiet hard to handle. A users tag containing multiple user tags would be much more simpler to handle.

Comment: mmm yes i have this xml `<response><sessid>jsh5ekqnt39117tmu5gjebkku4</sessid><session_name>Name Session</session_name><user>...</user><user>...</user><user>...</user></response>` and it's a web service answer, i can't change it.