# Trouble deserialising xml file using DataContractSerializer

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, datacontract

It's been awhile since i've used `DataContractSerializer` and i'm having a little trouble deserializing a xml file.

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SoftwareLicense xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">`

The error i'm getting is:

`{"Error in line 1 position 117. Expecting element 'SoftwareLicense' from namespace 'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Solentim.Modules.Licensing.Activation'.. 
Encountered 'Element'  with name 'SoftwareLicense', namespace ''. "}`

```
[DataContract(Name = "SoftwareLicense")]
public class SoftwareLicense : ISoftwareLicense
{
    ...
}
```

I've tried specifying the namespace which also doesn't work.

```
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(SoftwareLicense));

using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader =
                XmlDictionaryReader.CreateTextReader(stream, new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas()))
    {
        return (SoftwareLicense) serializer.ReadObject(reader);
    }
}
```

The namespace of the file has recently changed and an interface added to the class. I've resolved all other issues i just can't seem to get around this one.

I prefer to use the DatacontractSerializer as the class now has interface properties and XMLSerializer won't deserialise it

Comment: Since the error message is related to the xml, please provide the xml.

Comment: Why don't you use `XmlSerializer` as it makes things much easier?

Comment: Ah the XML was included but was stripped from the post, missed the `code` tag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16943176/how-to-deserialize-xml-using-datacontractserializer) may help you to solve your problem.

If you prefer to use `XmlSerializer`. Here is the simple implementation below:

```
private T Deserialize<T>(string path) where T : class
{
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
    T result = null;
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(path))
    {
       result = (T)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: I prefer to use the DatacontractSerializer as the class now has interface properties and XMLSerializer won't deserialise it

Comment: Managed to get this work. This was the solution i was using before trying `datacontractserializer`. The problem was the interfaces. I changed the design to not use interfaces in the serializable class